# Angular 2 - app breaks with typescript generated javascript files

Tags: angular

I am building a very simple app for learning purposes. This is my app component:

```
<div class="container">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <hr>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is what I have in the header component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    template: `
        <header class="row">
            <nav class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/messages']">Messenger</a></li>
                    <li routerLinkActive="active"><a [routerLink]="['/auth']">Authentication</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    `
})
```

The issue is when I am on the `/messages` url I get two header components for some reason:

[image]

I have tested things around and noticed that for some reason app breaks when typescript generates javascript files. When I deleted js files the app worked fine.
What could that be?

Comment: How does your routing module look like?

Answer (score 0):

It was my typescript package for atom compiling typescript files and with running npm run build that was compiling same files parallel which was breaking the app.

If anyone has the same issue, to disable the compiling by editor I added:

`"compileOnSave": false`

To the `tsconfig.json` file.